# web sites know the “real” access user(IP) through a proxy?

Tags: iptables, reverse-proxy, squid

I'm new to Squid and iptables, and am investigating whether they would be able to

accomplish a task at hand. part of my squid.conf:

```
acl wf myport 8010
acl vp myport 8020
acl ss myport 8030

cache_peer IP1 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=wflocal
cache_peer_access wflocal allow wf
cache_peer IP2 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=vplocal
cache_peer_access vplocal allow vp
cache_peer IP3 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=sslocal
cache_peer_access sslocal allow ss

cache_peer_access sslocal deny all
cache_peer_access vplocal deny all
cache_peer_access wflocal deny all
```

my squid ip is IP9

I need that the HTTP server IP1，IP2 and IP3 should logically

appear under a single URL hierarchy

like this :

```
    http  : // IP9:8010  

    http  : // IP9:8020 

    http  : // IP9:8030
```

all above is going well now

but the HTTP server access log can not know the "real" user IP and it just record ip of the accelerator(squid).what should I do to make the HTTP server IP1 , IP2 and IP3 record the "real" user IP.

Thanks for any insights on this!

Comment: Have you enabled [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) headers in Squid?

Comment: What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: apache and iis both support X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your squid passes your real ip address in HTTP header. You can disable it in squid.conf by

```
forwarded_for off
```

Comment: squid.conf  set forwarded_for = on and apache set X-Forwarded-For, then problem was solved